# how to count a list within a function

Tags: python

So i have a small working code, i only need to print the count of an occurrence but so far i have only been successful printing the actual occurrence.

I need to print just one number of how many times an item was >0

Comment: are you passing in a list of lists?

Comment: so, you are only missing `return count`

Comment: (and also, to test if an item is > 0, use `i > 0`,  not `i >= 0`)

Comment: If you want to print just a single value (or preferably, return that value), clearly you don't want to do that *within* either loop; you'll do so after the loops have finished.

Comment: you can also use a simpler expression : `return sum(len([i for i in x if i > 0]) for x in y)`

Comment: Jason, your edit deleting you example code makes you question much more unclear, and makes the answers hard to understand as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `return count` at the end.

```
def countpos(lsts):
     count = 0
     for lst in lsts:
         for val in lst:
             if val > 0:
                 count += 1
     return count

print countpos([[0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 6, 0]])  # 2
```

You could also use a generator to generate `1`s for every element that matches your condition, and then sum all the ones:

```
def countpos(lsts):
    return sum(1 for lst in lsts
                 for val in lst
                 if val > 0)

print countpos([[0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 6, 0]])  # 2
```

Comment: Thanks enrico. when i return the count it counts all the items in each list and i only need it to count items > 0

Comment: Use `>` instead of `>=`.

Comment: NM i had and '=' sign in there.

Answer (score 0):

```
def somefunction(y)
         count = 0
           for r in y:
               for i in r:
              if i >= 0:
                   count += 1
              #probably need to print the occurrence here.
```

print the answer outside of the all the loops using count which will have the answer stored

Answer (score 0):

```
input_lists = [[0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 6, 0]]
count = sum([1 for input_list in input_lists for i in input_list if i > 0])
```

You can make this into a function if you'd like, of course. Basically, you're just looping through the lists in input_lists then looping through the values in each list, checking if the value is greater than 0 and building a list of 1's for each time you find a value greater than zero. Finally, you just sum that list to get the count. The method being applied here is call list comprehension and it's a powerful technique. This one is a bit more complex than your typical first list comprehension because we're doing two nest comprehensions (two 'for' statements inside the list) and a condition (if)

Comment: you don't need to create a list, sum can accept the generator. that removes 1 iterating over the list.

Answer (score 0):

2 simpler methods :

With lambdas:

```
def count(y):
    return sum(map(lambda x: len(filter(lambda i: i > 0, x)), y))
```

Without:

```
def count(y):
    return sum(len([i for i in x if i > 0]) for x in y)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def somefunction(y)
     count = 0
     for r in y:
          for i in r:
              if i >= 0:
                   count += 1
     return count
```

The `return count` will return whatever the total is.

```
print somefunction(myListofLists)
```

printing this function will print the return statement.

Comment: Just a snippet of code with no explanation is next to useless as an answer.